# pgAdmin select from table with name in uppercase

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

using pgAdmin 4, postgres 9.6 on Windows 10

I have table in uppercase called `MYTABLE`. I encounter the following error when I do a select operation.

```
select count (*) from MYTABLE;
```

**Error**

```
ERROR:  relation "mytable" does not exist
LINE 1: select count (*) from MYTABLE;
                              ^
SQL state: 42P01
Character: 23
```

Comment: add dblquotes `select count (*) from "MYTABLE";`

Comment: that worked - could you please add the doc reference for this ?

Comment: Reference [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS).